# How to compute absolute integral?

Tags: python, math, scipy

Within python, I would like to calculate for an arbitrary function `y(x)` the absolute integral of that function between two values of `x`.

I know that I can calculate the 'normal' integral with the following function:

```
scipy.integrate.quad(y, x0, x1)
```

How can I calculate the absolute integral for a function?

With 'absolute' I mean, that the area where y is negative is also **added** to the resulting values of the integral and not subtracted.

For example: for the picture below, the result of the 'normal' integral from `-1` to `1` would be `0`, for the absolute integral the result would be `1`.

[image: y=x]

Comment: You can just calculate the normal integral of the absolute value of the function `|y|`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add `abs` to the result of your function, for example using a `lambda` construction:

```py
import scipy.integrate

def y(x):
    return x

x0, x1 = -1, 1
res = scipy.integrate.quad(y, x0, x1)
res_abs = scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: abs(y(x)), x0, x1)
```

`quad` returns a tuple: the estimated value of the result and the maximum error.

If your function isn't too heavy, you can also use [Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html), Python's [symbolic math](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) library. For example:

```py
from sympy import symbols, integrate

x = symbols('x', real=True)
y = x

x0, x1 = -1, 1
print(integrate(y, (x, -1, 1)))
print(integrate(abs(y), (x, -1, 1)))
```